# Rails polymorphic association self-referential associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, self-reference

I am trying to implement polymorphic association + self-referential associations.

The use case is:

I have two models

```
registered_user => registered users.
unregistered_friend => friends of registered users who have not registered.
```

I have a table

```
share (registered_user_id sharee_id sharee_type)
```

which stores data when

`registered_user` shares something with `sharee`

where `sharee` can be either `registered_user` or `unregistered_friend`

So basically what is the right way to go about it.

Should registered_user.rb have something like

```
has_many :share
has_many :share, :as => :sharee
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to specify different names for the associations of `registered_users` with `share`.

One named `shares`

```
has_many :shares,  :as => "sharee"
```

One named `sharers` or choose an appropriate name

```
has_many :sharers, :foreign_key => "registered_user_id", :class_name => "Share"
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, will check this and accept if it works